# Spring-ActiveMQ: DefaultMessageListenerContainer not getting destroyed

Tags: java, spring, queue, activemq-classic, spring-jms

I working with the Spring JMS DefaultMessageListenerContainer and initializing the queues on the init method of the spring and destroying the listnereContainer on destroy method.
But when i shutdown the tomcat server using "./catalina.sh stop" command, i getting the following exception when i tool the thread dump:

> "localhost-startStop-2" #155 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007fd4c0015800 nid=0x5265 in Object.wait() [0x00007fd4c4f60000]
>      java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
>           at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
>           - waiting on <0x00000007752ccae8> (a java.lang.Object)
>           at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:502)
>           at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer.doShutdown(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:545)
>           - locked <0x00000007752ccae8> (a java.lang.Object)
>           at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractJmsListeningContainer.shutdown(AbstractJmsListeningContainer.java:237)
>           at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractJmsListeningContainer.destroy(AbstractJmsListeningContainer.java:177)
>           at com.bng.ocg.queue.QueueConnection.destroy(QueueConnection.java:71)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

Here are the init and destroy methods:

```
public void init() {
    try {
        connection = pooledConnectionFactory.createConnection();
        session = connection.createSession(false,
                Session.DUPS_OK_ACKNOWLEDGE);

        updateDefaultQueue();
        updateDefaultConsumer();
    } catch (JMSException e) {
        Logger.sysLog(LogValues.error, this.getClass().getName(), coreException.GetStack(e));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Logger.sysLog(LogValues.error, this.getClass().getName(), coreException.GetStack(e));
    }
}

public void destroy(){
    for(DefaultMessageListenerContainer defaultMessageListenerContainer : defaultMessageListenerContainersCdrQueue)
        defaultMessageListenerContainer.destroy();

    for(DefaultMessageListenerContainer defaultMessageListenerContainer : defaultMessageListenerContainersDataSyncMsgQueue)
        defaultMessageListenerContainer.destroy();

    for(DefaultMessageListenerContainer defaultMessageListenerContainer : defaultMessageListenerContainersUrlHitterMsgQueue)
        defaultMessageListenerContainer.destroy();
    try {
        session.close();
    } catch (JMSException e) {
        Logger.sysLog(LogValues.error, this.getClass().getName(), coreException.GetStack(e));
    }
    try {
        connection.close();
    } catch (JMSException e) {
        Logger.sysLog(LogValues.error, this.getClass().getName(), coreException.GetStack(e));
    }
    pooledConnectionFactory.clear();
}

private void updateDefaultQueue() {
    for (int i = 0; i < cdrQueueInitialLength; i++) {
        cdrQueueList.add(cdrQueueNamePrefixString + i);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < dataSyncMsgQueueInitialLength; i++) {
        dataSyncMsgQueueList.add(dataSyncMsgQueueNamePrefixString + i);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < urlHitterMsgQueueInitialLength; i++) {
        urlHitterMsgQueueList.add(urlHitterMsgQueueNamePrefixString + i);
    }
}

private void updateDefaultConsumer() throws JMSException 
{
    /*for (int i = 0; i < cdrQueueInitialLength; i++) {
        defaultMessageListenerContainer = defaultMessageListenerContainerFactory
                .getObject();
        defaultMessageListenerContainer.setDestination(session
                .createQueue(cdrQueueList.get(i)));
        defaultMessageListenerContainer
                .setMessageListener(cdrMessageListener);
        defaultMessageListenerContainer.start();
        defaultMessageListenerContainersCdrQueue
                .add(defaultMessageListenerContainer);
    }*/

    for (int i = 0; i < dataSyncMsgQueueInitialLength; i++) {
        defaultMessageListenerContainer = defaultMessageListenerContainerDataSyncFactory
                .getObject();
        defaultMessageListenerContainer.setDestination(session
                .createQueue(dataSyncMsgQueueList.get(i)));
        defaultMessageListenerContainer
                .setMessageListener(dataSyncMsgListener);
        defaultMessageListenerContainer.start();
        defaultMessageListenerContainersDataSyncMsgQueue
                .add(defaultMessageListenerContainer);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < urlHitterMsgQueueInitialLength; i++) {
        defaultMessageListenerContainer = defaultMessageListenerContainerUrlHitterFactory
                .getObject();
        defaultMessageListenerContainer.setDestination(session
                .createQueue(urlHitterMsgQueueList.get(i)));
        defaultMessageListenerContainer
                .setMessageListener(urlHitterMsgListener);
        defaultMessageListenerContainer.start();
        defaultMessageListenerContainersUrlHitterMsgQueue
                .add(defaultMessageListenerContainer);
    }
}
```

Any suggestion to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think that your `destroy()` is not called ??

you have to add `@PreDestroy` to your `destroy()` method or use spring `@EventListener` or implements `ApplicationListener`

```
@EventListener({ ContextClosedEvent.class })
public void destroy() {

}


@Component
public class ContextClosed implements ApplicationListener<ContextClosedEvent> {

    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(final ContextClosedEvent event) {
       destroy(); // your destroy
    }
}
```